# existence of a signed measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, signed-measures

I want to show that there exists a signed measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ such that
$\mu((-\infty,x])=e^{3x}-e^x$ holds.

I already know that $\mu$ is defined on $\mathcal{B}$ since $\mu$ is defined on $\{(-\infty,x]|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Also $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$. Therefore I only have to show the sigma additivity of $\mu$.

I think I have to define a specific $\mu$ with $\mu((-\infty,x])=e^{3x}-e^x$ such that I can show the sigma additivity. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $\mu (E)=\int_{E\cap (-\infty, 0]} f(t)dt +\int_{E\cap (0,\infty)} f(t)dt$ where $f(t)=3e^{3t}-e^{t}$. The first term gives  a countably additive function because of integrability of $f$ on the negative real line. The second part is countably additive by Monotone Convergence Theorem since $f(x) > 0$ for $x >0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! I totally forgot about the Integral. Is it always like this that you divide the integral over $E$ in an integral over $E\cap B$ and an integral over $E\cap A$ with $A$ beeing a positive and $B$ beeing a negative set?

Comment: Why can´t we just write the integral over $E$?

Comment: @Jane It is easier to divide the proof onto the parts where $f$ is integrable and the part where it is non-ne gative so that we have an easy proof. What theorem would you apply if you combine the two terms?